# Is this memory safe?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.033 target:self selector:@selector(gameLoop)
     userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

I don't do anything to dealloc or kill this timer after starting it.
Is it safe? Or will it cause me to leak memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shouldn't leak memory. You're not retaining the timer. The run loop will retain it (I think), but it'll release it when it no longer needs it.

Comment: Yeah, the run loop will retain timers when they're scheduled.

Comment: Timers also retain their target. Therefore if an object that is also the timers target retains the timer, a retain cycle is formed.

Comment: Yes, timers will retain their target. So, It will mean timer always fire before target deallcated.

Answer (score 2):

The timer is retained by the run loop, so you don't need to retain it yourself.

However the timer will *retain its target*, so as long as it's repeating and you don't invalidate it, your target object won't be deallocated. You'll need to choose a good time to call `invalidate` on it which will cause the run loop to release it.

Note that you shouldn't also retain the timer yourself, at the risk of a retain cycle.

(I borked an answer to this very question yesterday and got schooled on it. Trying to atone.)

Comment: Ok i see this used in the GKTank sample application/code. It never gets set to invalidate. Is apple giving sample code thats bad? I try to learn from these samples -.-